# App that notifies when cursor is not moved for some time

Tags: windows, chrome, productivity

I struggle with getting distracted doing flashcards because of ADHD and it would really help.

If I don't move my mouse for 30 seconds (for example), make a beep. It could be either an app or an extension for Chrome.
I am using Windows 11

Comment: On which operating system(s) would you like the app to run?  Could you update your question (and tags) to include that info?  Thanks!

Comment: Added my system info, thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://tomeko.net/software/SIPclient/howto/IdleTime.7z - this not a dedicated application, but preconfigured softphone with plugin and script. It still is reasonably light though.

Time to "beep" is defined in IdleTime.lua script. If there is no interaction with PC (mouse, keyboard) it beeps periodically using same time as interval.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting is that [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) has that kind of functionality implemented [as variables](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#TimeIdle).

- `A_TimeIdle` measures it for any kind of input, no matter if made by user or not
- `A_TimeIdlePhysical` measures it for input made by user only
- `A_TimeIdleKeyboard` checks only keyboard input
- `A_TimeIdleMouse` checks only mouse input

With that in mind, you have a lot of script building possibilities. E.g. you could use [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetTimer.htm) to run periodic checks every 1-30 seconds that would check any of these values and if it's above 30 seconds, use a [SoundBeep](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SoundBeep.htm), play chosen sound with [SoundPlay](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SoundPlay.htm) or send a Windows notification with [TrayTip](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SoundPlay.htm). AHK has lots of various functionalities you could utilize to make it as suitable for your needs as required.

Alternatively, use a time tracking software like [Clockify](https://clockify.me/help/time-tracking/idle-detection-reminders#how-idle-detection-works). This can set it in minutes and it's not really a software made for that, but could maybe work for your use case.